# C++ Error while compiling a new class

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I've been trying to use de CodeBlocks IDE, and when a create a new class, I got an error at the beggining of the code:

Class.cpp :

```
#include "Class.h" // Error  (exactly the same message as I get in main.cpp
#include <iostream>

Class::Class()
{
    //ctor
}
```

Class.h

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H


class Class
{
    public:
        Class();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // CLASS_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class.h" // this line show me an error

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This message appears on the console fatal error: Class.h: No such file or directory

Directory of cpp classes : Workspace/Test/Sources/src/Classes

Directory of h    class : Workspace/Test/Headers/include/class

I tried to change to #include "Headers/include/Class.h" bud didn't work out

Any help is appreciate, bye.

Comment: You need to set your header search paths correctly.

Comment: You could use a relative directory: `../../../Headers/include/class` if the directories you list above include "/Classes" and "/class".  Still, it would be better to find the configuration screen for codeblocks where you can specify the include paths.

Comment: Use `-I../../../Headers/include/` as a command line argument when you compile in the Sources/src/Classes folder.

Comment: Thanks everyone, your comments and this link: http://www.jusuchyne.com/codingchyne/2011/03/codeblocks-failed-to-find-the-header-file/ helped me a lot, see you guys